# Pass function as parameter and execute it

Tags: javascript

I have a function that gets function as a parameter and measures time execution
of that function. But function that was passed as a parameter cannot execute and gives me: Uncaught TypeError: testFunc is not a function.

```
function measureTimeExecution(domID, testFunc){
//console.log(testFunc);
console.time("timer");
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   testFunc();
   var getDiv = document.getElementById(domID);
    getDiv.empty();
}
console.timeEnd("timer");
```

}

Cleans DOM

```
HTMLElement.prototype.empty = function() {
        var that = this;
        while (that.hasChildNodes()) {
            that.removeChild(that.lastChild);
        }
    };
```

Example of execution:

```
 measureTimeExecution("div1", createList_Task_2());
```

createTask_List_2 function:

```
function createList_Task_2(){
var createNewUL = document.createElement("ul");
createNewUL.id = "phoneList";
document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(createNewUL);
for(var i = 0; i < phones.length;i++){

    var createNewLi = document.createElement("li");
    var chunk = "<li>" + phones[i].age +"</li><br><li>" + phones[i].id +"</li><br><img src='"
        + phones[i].imageUrl  +"'/></li><br><li>"  + phones[i].name + "</li><br><li>" + phones[i].snippet + "</li>";

    createNewLi.innerHTML+= chunk;
    document.getElementById("phoneList").appendChild(createNewLi);
}
```

**EDITED**

I found why its didn't worked I'm didn't paid attention before that function execution was some old code that i forgot to delete. Now it runs fine. Thanks for replies

Comment: How does you call to `measureTimeExecution` look like?

Comment: Where is your `createList_Task_2` function defined?

Comment: Are these all in 1 file?

Comment: `createList_Task_2` seems to be missing a closing `}` so perhaps that's what's wrong? Btw. this is why proper indentation is really useful!

Comment: `.innerHTML = ""` fastest/shorter way to clean DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without brackets:

```
measureTimeExecution("div1", createList_Task_2);
```

When you include the brackets, you aren't passing the function; you are executing the function and passing its return value. Without the brackets (as shown) you are just passing a reference to the function which you can then call within your `measureTimeExecution` function using `testFunc()`.

It's not pretty but [this **fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qobgLm8L/) shows how it's done.

Comment: Are you sure that you've defined `function createList_Task_2() {}` somewhere? Look at the line the error occurs on, the first time it was probably on your `measureTimeExecution` line and after using my suggestion it was on the `testFunc()` line.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be able to pass the function as an argument.

From your code I cannot see when you actually run measureTimeExecution and you have not shown your definition of testFunc.

Make sure you have defined testFunc as a function and that it is accessible by measureTimeExecution.

Uncaught TypeError: testFunc is not a function usually means that testFunc is either out of scope or is not defined as a function.

Comment: and yeah do not pass the testFunc with brackets like jcuenod said.

try this:
console.log(typeof createList_Task_2);
measureTimeExecution("div1", createList_Task_2);

and tell me what the console log returns

Answer (score 0):

How did you call measureTimeExecution?

you need to do:

```
measureTimeExecution("div",function() { /*sometingh*/ });
```

or

```
function aFunction(){ /*something*/}
measureTimeExecution("div",aFunction);
```